# Intializing modules using Dagger is not in same order

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger 2 to initialise some modules in my app which I was initially initialising in my Application class. I want these modules to be initialised in a particular order. 
I am using an initialiser set to initialise my modules but they are executed in random order.

My initialiser module looks like this

```
@Module class InitializerModule {

    // initialize Profile library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initProfileLib(): Initializer = ProfileHelper()

    // initialize Video library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initVideoModule(): Initializer = VideoHelper()

    // initialize Video library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initQuestModule(): Initializer = QuestHelper()

    // initialize Audio library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initAudioModule(): Initializer = AudioHelper()

    // initialize Analytics library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initAnalyticsModule(): Initializer = AnalyticsHelper()

    // initialize Login library
    @Provides @IntoSet
    fun initLogin(): Initializer = LoginHelper() }
```

Code for App Module

```
@Module(includes = [InitializerModule::class])
open class AppModule {
}
```

Application class code

```
    class Application: DaggerApplication(){
    @set:Inject
        var initializerSet: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Initializer>? = null

      override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
        initDaggerComponent()
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
    for (init in initializerSet!!) {
         init.initialize(applicationContext)
      }
     }
   }
```

Every time I execute the code the order is random.

> ProfileHelper LoginHelper AnalyticsHelper VideoHelper QuestHelper
>   AudioHelper

My build.gradle

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.23.2"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.2"
```

How can I maintain the order of initialisation using Dagger?

Comment: Why do you want to create them in order? If there are inter-dependencies, express them explicitly and dagger will take care about the order. Otherwise it does not guarantee any particular order.

Comment: Yes there are interdependencies. What do I use to express them explicitly so dagger knows the order of execution.

Comment: Did you find a solution in this? I have a bunuch of trackers than set up rxjava listeners as well as publish events, and I need them to be in order!